# Avoiding variables as variable or list names in Python

Tags: python, variables, dynamic

I'd like to read in a number of text files that have the following structure:

```
3 560
7 470
2 680
4 620
3 640
...
```

The first column specifies conditions of a behavioral experiment, the second column reaction times. What I'd like to do is to create an array/list for each condition that contains the reaction times for this condition only. I've previously used Perl for this. As there are many different conditions, I wanted to avoid writing many separate elsif statements and therefore used the condition name in the array name:

```
push(@{condition.${cond}}, $rt);  # $cond being the condition, $rt being the reaction time
```

For example, creating an array like this:

```
@condition3 = (560, 640,...);
```

As I got interested in Python, I wanted to see how I would accomplish this using Python. I found a number of answers discouraging the use of variables in variable names, but have to admit that from these answers I could not derive how I would create lists as described above without reverting to separate elif's for each condition. Is there a way to do this? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thomas

Comment: Great! Thank you all very much for your quick and detailed help! I had not realized that it is possible to append values to existing keys in a dictionary, as all dictionary examples I had seen so far associated keys with only a single value.

Comment: Dictionaries only hold a single value for each key, but that single value can be a list.

Answer (score 4):

A dictionary would be a good way to do this. Try something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

conditions = defaultdict(list)

for cond, rt in data:
    conditions[cond].append(rt)
```

Answer (score 3):

The following code reads the file `data.txt` with the format you described and computes a dictionary with the reaction times per experiment:

```
experiments = {}
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]
for line in data:
    index, value = line.split()
    try:
        experiments[int(index)].append(value)
    except KeyError:
        experiments[int(index)] = [value]
print experiments
# prints: {2: ['680'], 3: ['560', '640'], 4: ['620'], 7: ['470']}
```

You can now access the reaction times per experiment using `experiments[2]`, `experiments[3]`, et cetera.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect application for a dictionary, which is similar to a Perl hash:

```
data = {}
with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            condition, value = map(int, line.strip().split())
            data.setdefault(condition, []).append(value)
        except Exception:
            print 'Bad format for line'
```

Now you can access your different conditions by indexing `data`:

```
>>> data
{2: [680], 3: [560, 640], 4: [620], 7: [470]}
>>> data[3]
[560, 640]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your question, as to why would you think about using elif conditions.

If you store a list of integers in a dictionary, the key being values of the first column a.k.a condition value, and its corresponding value a list of reaction times.

For example:
The dict would be like:

```
conditions['3'] -> [560, 640, ...]
```